# Copy image field data from SQL Server to Azure Blob Storage as blob blocks

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a table in SQL Server with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Documents (
   Id INT IDENTITY
  ,Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,Data IMAGE NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Documents_DocumentId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (DocumentId)
)
```

Is there any way to extract the data from this table and load it to Azure Blob Storage preserving the following structure:

- import-results

  - document-id

    - document-name

where 
 - document-id is actually id of a document (Id field) from Document table
 - document-name is name of a document (Name field) from Document table
 - the content of the block is Data field from Document table

I tried looking into Data Factory, but it looks like it can load only data of a query to a file, but I couldn't find the way to configure the described procedure.

P.S. this is like a part of migration from on-prem data to cloud and the goal is to avoid storing terabytes of documents in SQL server database by replacing this with blobs in Blob Storage.

Comment: Can you use a programming language such as `.net`?  If so, it would be relatively easy retrieve images from database, convert to `byte[]` and upload as blobs to a storage account.  If you are trying to this with straight `sql`, I don't know of a way to achieve that.

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @sgeddes yes, I can use .NET. It's just a question about amount of data and time on such kind of migration. Plus, such custom solution should be error-proof and validated by our regulatory.
So, I'm keeping this as a last choice :)

Comment: @marc_s we are moving to a new application and new data schema - so we won't store files in the database at all. But, yes - I'm with you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do just want to avoid storing terabytes of documents in sql server database. I suggest you adopting below steps.

Step 1: Retrieve images data and upload them into Azure Blob Storage as image files.

Step 2: Just use Azure Data Factory to import data from sql database into Azure Table Storage.

Step 3：Get image `urls` which stored in Azure Blob Storage to store them into Data field.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: right, that is what we already did.. But now we need to migrate data from old application from on-prem to Azure.. And I need to move these documents somehow from SQL Server to Blob Storage

Comment: @al0kha Could you just use sdk to upload data to blob storage?

Comment: I can, but like I said I’m looking for ADF solution. Custom tool is my last option. I’ll try to use Blob Storage API within my pipeline

Comment: @al0kha If you crash new errors,please post here so that I could help you to solve it.